# Explanation on a particular direct limit

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Given the direct system $$\mathbb{Z}^2 \xrightarrow{A} \mathbb{Z}^2 \xrightarrow{A}\mathbb{Z}^2 \xrightarrow{A}\cdots$$ with $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$ the direct limit should be $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$.

How is this done? Well, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1$ and $2$ with eigenvectors $(-1,2)^T$ and $(1,1)^T$ respectively. The best I can do right now is to show that the limit contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$...

The reason why I am asking is because by replacing $A$ above with $A' = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, then even though $A'$ has eigenvalues $-2$ and $3$, the direct limit in this case cannot be the direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{3}]$.

Comment: Just a quick remark : you might want to precise in which category you're looking for the colimit. (I imagine from the context that you're working in the category of $\mathbb Z$-modules, but it's worth clearing things out.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The direct limit of this system is isomorphic to the direct limit of 
$$
\Bbb Z^2\xrightarrow{S}\Bbb Z^2\xrightarrow{S}\Bbb Z^2\xrightarrow{S}\dotsb
$$
where $S$ is the [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of $A$. In this case, the Smith form of $A$ is
$$
S=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and we have $UAV=S$ where
\begin{align*}
U &=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 2&-1\end{pmatrix} & V &=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see that right now...

Comment: The point is that you're free to change basis in every copy of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ simultaneously.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - Sure, but why does that fail when one considers $A'$ given above? That is what I am trying to understand...

Comment: @Eric You want to consider the smith form of $A^\prime$. The problem with diagonalization is that the change of basis matrices are automorphisms of $\Bbb Z$ if and only if their determinants are $\pm 1$ which fails in this case. In your case, the Smith form of $A^\prime$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 6\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick - Can you please give me the change of basis matrix for $A$ above? Thanks!

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick, but wouldn't $U$ and $V$ always have determinant $\pm 1$? And isn't that the change of basis matrix $T$ acts as $T^{-1}AT$? So in the original direct system $\{\mathbb{Z}^2, A\}$, what is the change of basis matrix to obtain $\{\mathbb{Z}^2, S\}$, which as you said would fail to be an automorphism when $A'$ is considered instead?

Comment: @Eric I'm not sure if I understand your question. I'm claiming that if $\{X_i\xrightarrow{f_{ij}} X_j\}$ is a direct system and $\phi_i$ is an automorphism of $X_i$, then $\{X_i\xrightarrow{\phi_j\circ f_{ij}\circ\phi_i}X_j\}$ is a direct system with isomorphic direct limit.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick - sorry for the confusion, in your comment earlier, you said that "The problem with diagonalization is that the change of basis matrices are automorphisms of Z if and only if their determinants are ±1 which fails in this case." But we can also write $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\-3&1\end{pmatrix}A'\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&-1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&6\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Eric Still not sure if I understand, but I'm getting tired and should probably stop trying to answer math questions. Hopefully someone else can clear this up and, if I've made a mistake, correct my answer.